# Node that creates another one which reads its values dynamically

Tags: nodes, pgfkeys

I'm trying to understand how the expansion of a `\pgfextra` which in turn is inside an `append after command` is done. My idea is to read some value from a `pgf` key when the `append after command` code is executed, but I'm afraid the code is being expanded on the style definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfkeys{
    /my label/.initial=initial,
}

\tikzset{my node/.style={
    draw=red,
    minimum size=1cm,
    node contents=#1,
    append after command={
        \pgfextra
        \draw [-Implies, double, shorten >=2ex] (\tikzlastnode.south) -- +(0, -1cm);
        \path [use as bounding box] (\tikzlastnode.south west) rectangle ($ (\tikzlastnode.south west) + (0, -1cm) $);
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1.5cm}}
        \pgfnode{rectangle}{base}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/my label}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
        \endpgfextra
    }
}}

\fill (-1, 1) [white] rectangle (1, -2);
\node at (0, 0) [/my label=label, my node=1] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get

[image: actual result]

vs what I'm trying to achieve

[image: desired result]

What I eventually want to do is to draw two nodes like the image from above that can be fully referenced later by only specifying one node, for example:

```
% this create a node with `name` and `node contents` K and a node below with `name` and `node contents` V.
% the argument V could be set here or read dynamically from a pgf key)
\node [key=K, value=V] 

\draw [->] (K.north) -- +(0, 1);
\draw [->] (V.south) -- +(0, -1);
```

Any way to achieve this or must I specify two nodes manually?

Comment: \pgfextra turns off the tikz parser and treats the argument as standard LaTeX.  OTOH, `/.expand once` etc. can be use with pgfkeys to expand a macro before entering it.  See page 990.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to solve your problem in a particular way, using the key system of tikz and pre- and post-expansions. I cannot contribute to this in any way.

Just in case you consider also other approaches: I suggest to use plain macros.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% \KeyValue[options for the upper node]{position}{name of upper node}{name of lower node}
\newcommand\KeyValue[4][]{%
  \node[draw=red,minimum size=1cm,#1] (#3) at (#2) {3};
  \draw[-Implies,double] (#3) -- +(0, -1cm) node[below,inner sep=1pt](#4){#4};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \KeyValue{0,0}{1}{label}
  \draw [->] (1.north) -- +(0, 1);
  \draw [->] (label.south) -- +(0, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]